# What else can I use to execute $timeout function in my unit test (none deferred functions)? (Angular/Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have this function here:

```
$scope.attachDataTooltips = function() {

    setTimeout(function() {

        if (!$scope.isContentLoaded.state) {
            $scope.attachDataTooltips();
        } else {
            $timeout(function() {
                // enable the popover plugin
                jQuery('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
                $scope.isKioskIdLoaded.state = true;
                $scope.isSerialNumberLoaded.state = true;
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
};
```

I tried using $timeout.flush() but realized it used for synchronously flushing a queue of deferred functions. With a regular setTimeout, I was able to use

```
    beforeEach(inject(function() {
        //$timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        jasmine.clock().install();
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });
```

and 
 jasmine.clock().tick(1000);

to execute what is inside the setTimeout() but I am having difficulties executing what is inside the $timeout function().

Comment: Did you try using `$timeout.flush()` and then `scope.$digest()` ?

Comment: Yeah I still couldn't get it to work. Do you know if $timeout.flush() ONLY works with deferred functions though? The examples I have seen only utilize deferred functions.

Comment: The problem is because of `setTimeout` ?

Comment: Maybe? You think because $timeout is nested within setTimeout it breaks it? I tried another scope.function that has a $timeout function and it still didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Yes ofcourse $timeout.flush will only handle $timeout, not setTimeout.

Comment: Yeah I know that I am not using $timeout.flush for the setTimeout, I am using the jasmine.clock()